# Как называть все формы глагола, кроме инфинитива?

Tags: грамматика

Как называть все формы глагола, кроме инфинитива? *Косвенные* формы (как падежи)?

> В *косвенных* формах у глагола *прийти* ***й*** пропадает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. О косвенных падежах**

В русском языке **6 основных падежей,** при этом И.п — это **начальная** форма, а остальные называются **косвенными**. Классификация ясна и понятна.

Почему так? **Начальная форма** — это основное (прямое)  название предмета,  а другие падежные формы изменяют (искажают) основное название и считаются **непрямыми** (косвенными, косыми). Этот термин является  **калькой с латинского языка.** Классификация ясна и понятна.

**Косвенный.** Заимствование из старославянского; выражение «косвенные падежи» было образовано как калька с латинского ***casus obliqui.*** К той же основе восходит и прилагательное косой.

2. **Можно ли говорить о косвенных формах глагола**, ведь инфинитив тоже считается начальной формой. Если даже можно, то не нужно, потому что в этом нет смысла. Инфинитив называет действие **в общем виде**, но более значимым он не является. В синтаксисе это скорее **вспомогательная** форма.

**[А сколько у глагола вообще форм?](https://dzen.ru/a/YQE-v0WrSAhEpC9v)** У него есть начальная форма, или инфинитив (в переводе с латинского — "неопределённый"), формы изъявительного наклонения, повелительного и сослагательного. В изъявительном наклонении обычно так: **6 форм** настоящего времени, **4 формы** прошедшего времени, **6 форм** в будущем времени. В прошедшем времени **4 формы**.

В повелительном наклонении **2 формы.** В сослагательном, или условном наклонении, 4 формы: они образуются присоединением частицы бы к формам прошедшего времени.

Таким образом, у глагола может быть **более 20 форм,** но никто не делит их на начальную  и косвенные формы.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, в русском языке инфинитив не является основной формой глагола и образуется стандартным прибавлением или -ть, -ить или -ать к корню, стандартизация указывает как раз на то, что это явление новое и не лежит в основе языковой грамматики. Основных форм глагола в русском скорее всего две - настоящего и прошедшего. При том, что формы прошедшего и настоящего времени часто бывают из разных родовых групп: иду - шёл(от шед-шаг, корень ш), есть(от ем) -был(от бы, быть), росту(от рост) - рос, лезу-лез, горю-горел, живу - жил, вижу(не от вид)-видел(от вид)-виждь(тоже нехарактерная форма), а вот инфинитив видеть опять от вид, бью-бил(оба связаны с бой, так что корень б-бь) - б+и+ть(стандартно), живу-жил(жи-, жи-знь), лечу-летел(корень лет-, лететь от летел, полёт от лет-), чту-читаю - читал - читать, но прочту(корень чт* - чёт, счёт, читка и тп.), чешу-чесал-по+чешу(чеш-чес)-чес+ать, грущу(не от грусть)-груст+ил-груст+ить(от грусть или наоборот), вру-варю-верю - врал-варил-верил - врать-варить-верить - на+врать-у+варить-по+верить.

То есть очевидно, что инфинитив не разу не начальная форма для большинства глаголов. Что же касается форм будущего времени, то там вообще много разных, не только от инфинитива, и от настоящего времени и от второго лица, и от третьего, от множественного третьего - вру-ври-врёт-врать - совру-соври(соврите)-соврёт(соврёте)-соврут-соврать, а таже прибавлением буду - буду врать.

А вот склонение женского рода образует отдельную форму только в прошедшем времени - врал-врала - соврал-соврала, формы будущего и настоящего не отражают форм женского рода, ну и к инфинитиву тоже отношения не имеет.

Comment: Можете еще рассказать об  этимологии слова "косвенный", то есть почему падежи так называют, кроме И.п.  Было бы познавательно.

Comment: @Sharon косвенный - от слова касаться, кос+венный - лист+венный, коса - связанный то есть, но каким образом связанный не уточняется, относящийся к (основной форме) - тоже может быть. Коса как инструмент скорее всего от того, что снопы вяжут, косить ~ вязать сено.

Comment: Не, но это же калька с латинского,  а в переводе - косые, или не прямые, названия. Они не прямо называют предмет, а через измененную падежную форму.

Comment: @Sharon ну хорошо, пусть будет косой, не прямой, огибающий. Но проблема в том, что именная форма - это от формы, то есть формальный язык. Прямая коса у девушки тоже ведь коса. Как это, прямая коса?)

Comment: А вы не знаете как? Коса - от слова чесать, лингвисты уверяют что это старшее название, и-е корень. Косой - это не прямой. Вот говорят же: опять накосячил.

Comment: @Sharon это же сленг) Короче ладно. Есть понятие косвенный, то есть не связанный напрямую, однако, связанный с главным словом или словоформой - именительным падежом. Тут есть ряд моментов, что как бы да, но как бы возможно это не совсем так, потому что слова могут быть связаны по иному принципу, а именно через грамматику, то есть общие отношения, но образовывать группы родственных слов. Аристотель вводил понятие родственных слов, то есть связанных, без уточнения, какое слово является главным. В случае же с глаголами, глаголы настоящего и прошедшего времени образуют собственные роды.

Comment: Называть эти роды косвенными я бы не стал, так какое слово главное, сложно сказать. Но уже ветви слов образованных от этих глаголов могут, наверное, считаться косвенными, хотя зачем, если термин косвенный используется для падежей, зачем мешать падежи с родами глаголов?